# Root user unable to see files/directories

Tags: permissions, root

Preface: This is a digital ocean droplet setup using serverpilot. There are two users, `root` and `serverpilot`.

When I SSH in as `serverpilot` I can see the files listed inside of `apps/website/public/`, but when I SSH in as `root` and cd into `apps/website/public/` and `ls -la` there are a number of files and directories that are not listed.

As an example, `serverpilot` can see `style.css`

```
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 serverpilot serverpilot    22322 Nov 17 22:05 style.css
```

As another example, here are a few other files that `root` cannot see but `serverpilot` can.

```
drwxr-xr-x+ 13 serverpilot serverpilot     4096 Apr 18 11:42 wp-content
-rwxrwxr-x+  1 serverpilot serverpilot     3286 May 24  2015 wp-cron.php
drwxr-xr-x+ 18 serverpilot serverpilot    12288 Dec  7 17:35 wp-includes
```

But when I SSH in as `root` and cd into `apps/website/public` and `ls -la` this is all thatI see.

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data www-data    4096 Apr 17 22:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root        4096 Oct 14  2016 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data      46 Oct 21 15:11 .user.ini
```

Checking both `root` and `severpilot` groups displays:

```
root : root www-data lxd sp-sysusers users serverpilot
serverpilot : serverpilot lxd sp-sysusers
```

I'm not sure what happened and why root user has lost access to the directories and files.

I've tried resetting file permission, `chown` and `chown` with a group name, but am still unable to get the files to show up for `root`. Since I'm fairly new to linux server management, I feel like it may be something simple that I am overlooking.

Edit:

Some of the comments below recommended running `getfacl` to get more info on a file since it appears that ACLs is overriding the file permissions.

The output of `getfacl` on `style.css` is as follows:

```
# owner: serverpilot
# group: serverpilot
user::rwx
user:www-data:r-x
group::r-x
group:serverpilot:rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

Is it possible that the user should be `serverpilot:r-x` and not `www-data:r-x`?

Comment: The `+` after the file mode in the `ls -l` listing means that there are ACLs on the files. ACLs override the file mode.

Comment: `+` and the end means that `ACL` is applied, use `getfacl` command to get more info

Comment: the interaction between ACL:s and the normal permission bits is a bit more complicated than a simple override. But I don't think they should prevent `root` from having special access to everything.

Comment: @EHerman, What comes to mind is that are you sure you are looking at the same directory? The path you gave was relative, not an absolute path so make sure you're not looking at another copy of a similar directory structure. If that's not the case, then I'd start thinking about other, more advanced permission tools. SELinux?

Comment: @user1700494 I've gone ahead and updated the original posting with the `getfacl` output on `style.css` mentioned above.

Comment: @ilkkachu I'm sure these are the same directories, unfortunately. I can take a look into SELinux. I know I fudged these permissions up at some point, but I'm only just realizing now that root user doesn't have access to where it once did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I feel completely stupid, but I guess everyone has to start somewhere. The issue was indeed what @ilkkachu had mentioned in their comment. When I ssh in as root it was dropping me in a `/root/` directory which lived elsewhere on the server. Not sure why I didn't check this.

When I `ssh` in as `serverpilot` it was placing me in the correct directory where my files/folders should be. For some reason, some of these files were duplicated in the `/root/` directory as well.

Updating permissions on one of the parent directories, I was able to CD out of the directory and down into the proper directory where I needed to be.

Now to investigate how to setup root user to be dropped in the proper folder.

Thanks all.